# Git - fatal: failed to open, fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly after clone

Tags: git, command-line-interface

This is for `Windows 10`, and the commands are ran from `Git Bash`, I am running `Git v2.21.0`.

I am creating a brand new `bare` repository and trying to figure out how it all works. I have had success to get connected, `push`, `pull`, `add`, `commit` etc. The one thing I keep having issues with is getting this error after  trying to clone the same remote location repository under a different name. Even if I delete the local repository named after the remote location, I still can't do it. Here are my steps, for both my local machine and the server.

**Server**

```
$ git init rep.git --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in //myLocation/rep.git/
```

**Local PC**

```
$ git clone //myLocation/rep.git
Cloning into 'rep'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

$ cd rep

$ echo 123 > file.txt

$ git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in file.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

$ git commit -m'adding file'
[master (root-commit) 6ae32fb] adding file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file.txt

$ git push
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 216 bytes | 72.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To //myLocation/rep.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

So up to here everything is all dandy, next is the problem:

```
$ git clone //myLocation/rep.git rep2
Cloning into 'rep2'...
fatal: failed to open '//myLocation/rep.git/objects/19/(sha1_stuff)'
  : Function not implemented
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have recreated this many times. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: which version of git did you use?  I cannot recreate this error with 2.16 on linux.

Comment: 2.21.0 - this is done on a Windows PC using `Git Bash`

Comment: tried 2.18 on windows, still not reproducer. I do not have 2.21. but it looks like there is a bug in this version or a problem with installation.

Comment: @Serge I appreciate you trying it out.